# Qlikview + extension. How to change sheet using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, qlikview

I'm building a google maps extension for qlikview.

I struggle to find how to change the active sheet from JavaScript.

UPDATE: I appreciate the question might lack the description, but I don't know what else to add. I spent ages looking for the answer on the web + the JS manual from Qlikview is really not the best thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is having the same problem, here is the solution

```
Qv.GetCurrentDocument().binder.Set("Document.TabRow.Document\\SH01", "action", "", true)
```

Just change the sheet ID ("SH01" above) to the one you want to switch to.